# What are the boundary conditions on Green's function and why?

Tags: boundary-value-problem, greens-function

The equation $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\phi(x)=f(x)\tag{1}$$ has the general solution $$\phi(x)=\phi_0(x)+\int G(x,x')f(x')dx^\prime\tag{2}$$ where $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}G(x,x^\prime)=\delta(x-x^\prime)\tag{3}$$ and $\phi_0$ is any solution of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\phi_0(x)=0$.

Usually, problem (1) is accompanied by some boundary conditions such as $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$ but $G$ is not. However, the solution of (1) using (2), requires us to know the solution of (3). But the solution of (3), in turn, requires boundary conditions on $G$ which does not come with the problem. If the boundary condition on $G$ is not known, how is it possible to find a unique solution to $(1)$?

Answer (score 0):

In one dimension there exist several possible Green functions for the whole domain $\mathbb R\,:$
$$\tag{1}
G(x,x')=\max(x-x',0)\,,\quad\text{ or },\quad G(x,x')=\frac{|x-x'|}{2}\,.
$$
These functions satisfy (3) and are therefore fundamental solutions.

The problem with them is however that they are unbounded and will not yield
a solution of the Poisson equation
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\phi(x)=f(x)\,,\quad x\in\mathbb R\,,
$$
for every $f\,.$

Nonetheless, the following should work
(since the Wikipedia article about the [Poisson equation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson-Gleichung) that explains how you treat other domains and boundary conditions is only in German let me transcribe it briefly):

- Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R$ be a bounded interval, $\Omega=[a,b]\,.$ Let $\phi_0(x)$ be the solution of
  $$
  \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\phi^{x'}=0\,,\quad \text{ in }\quad (a,b)\,,
  $$
  satisfying the boundary conditions
  $$
  \phi^{x'}(a)=G(a,x')\,,\quad \phi^{x'}(b)=G(b,x')\,.
  $$
- The Green function for $[a,b]$ with boundary conditions $\phi(a)=0=\phi(b)$ is then
  $$
  G_{[a,b]}(x,x')=G(x,x')-\phi^{x'}(x)
  $$
  where $G(x,x')$ is one of the functions from (1).